# Webpage hangs while using Iframe to display a local HTML

Tags: html

So as mentioned in the title, the current 'tab' of my web browser hangs when direct an Iframe to load a local .html file (when a link is clicked). The file is placed in the same folder, under the name 'Query1.html'. Here is a section of the code.

```
<table>
<td id = "td01">
<a href="file://Query1.html" target="if01">Query1</a>
</td> </table>
<Iframe width=500px height=500px name="if01">
</Iframe>
```

I apologize if the question is stupid, and thanks in advance.
[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8QnUfRAn9lKYmNSMk9GdmNVczg/view?usp=sharing) to original .html file (which is called Doubt#1.html).

Comment: Have you tried `file:///`?

Comment: @sideroxylon I just did. It says- Page cannot be displayed.

Comment: What error messages are you getting in the console?

Comment: @sideroxylon Really sorry, but what console. I'm using notepad by the way. Sorry if that is amateur.

Comment: The browser console (usually under Developer Tools) - launch it and then re-load your page.  If there are error messages, they will be displayed in the console.

Comment: @sideroxylon Oh that console! It gives no errors..

Comment: @InfiniteParadox check my answer below, that must be working, If any problem comment on Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<a href="URL" target="target_name"> Iframe </a>`

In this case `<a href="Query1.html" target="if01">Query1</a>`

**Note 1 :** `Query1.html` must be in same folder, otherwise use `/path/to/yourfile.html` no need for `file:///`

**Note 2 :** If you are using `file:///` then you have to provide complete path like `file:///D:/folder1/folder3/folder4/yourfile.html`

Comment: I tried that earlier but it didn't seem to work, and oddly enough it does now. Perhaps I was wrong with the syntax. Thanks again anyways.

Comment: Actually I'm not 15 rep yet, so I can't yet. Beginning to learn HTML 5.